# How would I remove this from all wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

In every wordpress post I have code like this -

```
<img src="http://domain/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Black-Bosch-Avantixx-HBM13B261B-Electric-Double-Oven-300x266.jpg" alt="black-bosch-avantixx-hbm13b261b-electric-double-oven" width="300" height="266" class="alignright size-medium wp-image-367913" />
```

Obviously each post is a different name, how can I remove this paragraph inside all posts as I have thousands. 
Is there a command I can do using phpmyadmin?
Step by step would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have try to delete the img? Do you have use some plug-in downloaded from external website? I don't think you need db i think it's something in JS or php if this you can use add to your js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".wp-image-367913").css("display","none")            
});
```

If it's only the code, you need to check your article.php or single.php or your post php page  file and see if there are this link write some where.

Comment: Hi, all images from the site are deleted, I am left with the code in thousands of my posts, would be great to remove that code from all. Thought maybe a commmand in phpmyadmin would have worked or something, not the most technically gifted regarding these things unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have check the php fils? because this look like the code be inside the php files.
http://localhost:8888/..../wp-content/themes/name-theme/phpfile...

Comment: The code is in the actual posts, for example I see it in post_content for all posts, and no images are on the server, all deleted. Any sort of command to remove the code completely from inside post_content, or try to explain what I should do, as not fully understanding, appreciate your help though ;)

Comment: In some part must be written the code. I think you need found where is and not use other code for delete. Maybe could be some plug-in. I don't have understand if the code are in all article page or only in the last article.